# Problem referencing C++ /clr project from C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have compiled a native C++ project using the /CLR switch ("gloox", an XMPP library). The build succeeded and I'm able to reference it from a C# project (ie it shows up in the References folder). The C++ project exposes some classes under the namespace 'gloox'.

I can also see the gloox {} namespace in the object browser, along with all the exported classes.

The problem is that from the C# project I can't 'see' the gloox namespace (ie 'using gloox' does not compile).

Thanks

Comment: If you look in the Object Browser in Visual Studio, can you see any types exported by the gloox project? That should tell you what the full namespace is.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Yes, I can see the gloox {} namespace in the OB. (Edited main question)

Answer (score 2):

Does the C++ project expose any managed types (`ref class` or `value class` or `enum class`)?  The `/CLR` option doesn't magically make types available to managed code, you need the managed metadata which is only available for managed types, and the types need to be public to be used from other assemblies.

(To be totally accurate, the C++/CLI compiler sometimes creates metadata for native classes, especially in `/clr:pure` mode, but marks these as internal so you can't use them from other languages which don't understand the native C++ rules.)

Comment: I believe Ben has the right answer here.  The official distribution of of gloox is a standard C++ code, and it doesn't use the C++/CLI syntax to declare managed types.  Simply building with /clr won't make standard C++ types "visible" to C# or other CLS-compliant languages.  You could add managed "wrapper" classes to gloox that call down to the unmanaged gloox classes and marshal data back and forth.  The advantage of /clr is that it can make that sort of wrapping more seamless than using a bunch of DllImport's.